# Interagir/Buscar Button pela sua Tag usando WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button

Tenho uma tela com 25 botões e gostaria de interagir com os botões através do código.

Por exemplo, um numero é gerado usando a função `Random`:

```
Random rdn = new Random();
numero = rdn.Next(0,25);
```

Digamos que o resultado foi 20. Como faço para chamar esse botão que possui a *tag* 20 e então mudar a cor de *background* dele?

```
myButton(????).Background = Brushes.Red;
```

Sei que poderia fazer um por um:

```
        if (numero == 1)
        {
            BTN_1.Background = Brushes.Red;
        }
        if (numero == 2)
        {
            BTN_2.Background = Brushes.Red;
        }
```

Mas não seria o certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei a resposta do jeito que eu gostaria que ficasse.

```
string str = "00";
foreach (Control c in Grid.Children)
{
   if (c is Button && c.Tag.ToString() == str)
      {
          ((Button)c).Background = Brushes.Red;
      }
}
```

valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente teria que transformar estes botões `BTN_1`, `BTN_2`, etc. em um vetor de botões. Assim teria um `BTN[1]`, `BTN[2]`, etc. (eu trocaria os nomes dos botões, mas é gosto). Assim você tem um índice que pode ser aplicado o número que foi sorteado.

```
BTN[numero].Background = Brushes.Red;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WPF/ChangeBackground.cs).

Não sei como fazer isto em WPF, talvez [essa pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2481769/221800) te ajude. Parece que ter[a que criar com código C# e não XAML.

Comment: Achei a resposta... @bigown. Devo responder a minha própria pergunta? Não sei se isso é correto. Obrigado

Comment: @Ayo sim, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2673547/2556111) no SOen que remete para esta [classe](https://code.google.com/p/gishu-util/source/browse/WPF/Utilities/DepObjExtn.cs) no code.google.

A classe declara vários métodos de extensão que permitem procurar por um Filho dentro de um (Control)Pai<sup>(1)</sup>. A procura pode ser feita por tipo ou tipo + critério.

No seu caso, supondo que todos os botões estão no mesmo StackPanel, para encontrar o botão com a tag = 20 seria assim:

```
var myButton = stackPanel.FindChild<Button>(button => (int)button.Tag == 20);
myButton.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> Mais concretamente um DependencyObject</sub>